# cURL to PHP: Parse-Server push notifications

Tags: php, curl, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I would like to push notification with cURL to all Users.

Here is my .php:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://myApp.herokuapp.com/parse/push';
$data = array(
    'channels' => '',
    'type' => 'ios',
    'data' => array(
        'title' => 'test',
        'alert' => 'greetings programs',
    ),
);
$_data = json_encode($data);
$headers = array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id:xx',
    'X-Parse-Master-Key:xx',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key:xx',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

When I run this php, that logs :

```
{"result":true}
```

But I don't have notification on my app.
How can I solve this with my code ?

When I'm looking in my DB, I can find the push notif:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "570ea4695b1cec1100583fb4"
    },
    "objectId": "Kt6PI0vRHI",
    "pushTime": "2016-04-13T19:56:25.251Z",
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2016-04-13T19:56:25.251Z"
    },
    "query": "{\"channels\":{\"$in\":\"\"}}",
    "payload": {
        "title": "test",
        "alert": "greetings programs"
    },
    "source": "rest",
    "title": null,
    "expiry": null,
    "status": "failed",
    "numSent": 0,
    "pushHash": "e08f4b8382fdee50fb6547236c7ea2a3",
    "_wperm": [],
    "_rperm": [],
    "errorMessage": "{\"code\":107,\"message\":\"bad $in value\"}"
}
```

Comment: I would rather create a cloud function for sending push notifications and call that function with php because this way you don't have to transmit masterkey over the network...

Comment: @MazelTov thanks for replying ! How can I make that ?  I tried to push notification with cloud code, but that didn't work. Please see my topic for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584922/parse-server-ios-push-notification